# how do i find IP of wired access point

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I'm at a friends house that is using ATT Uverse. This network is by default secured. The problem is they have a long ethernet cable plugged into a "Linksys Access point A+G", which is unsecured. Its broadcasting 'linksys-a' and 'linksys-g', both of which a lot of filthy vagrants are connecting to.

I'm trying to secure it, but any time i connect to the default gateway IP it goes directly to the Uverse router admin page, and not the linksys one.

I've tried going to the list of connected wired devices and putting in every single IP and it either doesnt work, or is something else. I really have no idea how i access this linksys backend area :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Linksys Access Point is probably not showing up as a connected device because it is functioning as an access point. You don't need to reset it; it's functioning just fine. 
The device you have is *probably* a WAP55AG, which has a default IP of 192.168.1.246 ([Source](http://www6.nohold.net/Cisco2/ukp.aspx?pid=80&vw=1&articleid=4117)). If that doesn't do the trick, Linksys Access Point IPs are usually in the range of 192.168.1.245 to 192.168.1.255, so one of those should be the IP of yours.

Comment: holy crap that worked! I seriously was going nuts because no IP was showing up in netstat, even after resetting it and wiring it in.... the problem is now its asking for authentication and ive tried admin/blank, admin/admin, admin/password and blank/blank. do you know the default?

Comment: @Tallboy The default is blank/admin. (No username & 'admin' as the password) Edit: Ninja'd; ah well.

Answer (score 4):

All APs will have a means of resetting their settings to the defaults. On Linksys devices there will be a reset button that can be accessed with a paper clip. With the device on, push the paper clip into the hole and watch the lights on the front... that should all go off, and come back on as it reboots.

Google the exact model of the AP and it should tell you what the default IP address and credentials of to login via the web (it's is probably 192.168.1.245, with no user name, but a password of admin). Set your PC up to have a static IP in the same subnet(e.g. 192.168.1.200) and hook up a crossover cable from the PC directly to the AP, or use a hub/switch in between with a regular ethernet cable. Once logged in you can set up the wireless security however you like. When you're done, plug the AP back into the wired network. The UVerse router will then give it a DHCP address and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks! perfect advice, i used your answer to find the login :) wish i could mark both as 'answer'

Comment: +1 for same subnet; xxx.xxx.(1).xxx ; My network runs (0) : [how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/)

Answer (score 2):

Unplug the AP from the network (leave the power plugged in), 
[Reset it to factory defaults](http://www6.nohold.net/Cisco2/ukp.aspx?pid=80&app=vw&vw=1&login=1&json=1&docid=1614d59ad48f4c9aae8622b513f98ba3_4123.xml),

[image]

Plug it directly into your computer via Ethernet,

[image]

Default IP addresses of some Linksys access points:

```
WAP11   - 192.168.1.251 
WAP51AB - 192.168.1.250 
WAP54GP - 192.168.1.245 
WAP55AG - 192.168.1.246 
WAP54G  - 192.168.1.245
```

[Configure it from scratch](http://www6.nohold.net/Cisco2/ukp.aspx?pid=80&vw=1&articleid=4117) ensuring it's [secured](http://www6.nohold.net/Cisco2/ukp.aspx?pid=80&app=vw&vw=1&login=1&json=1&docid=ae906c6c1eb44d259ef698fcaabf91a5_4190.xml).

Comment: Actualy for my WAP55AG the default was also 245. Thanks for the information though!